# Enabling TLSv1.0 in OpenLDAP on CentOS7

Tags: centos7, openldap

Despite setting `olcTLSProtocolMin: 3.1`, only TLS1.2 is being presented by my CentOS7 OpenLDAP server.

I currently need TLSv1.0 to support a legacy application that cannot yet be replaced.

How can I make TLSv1.0 available on OpenLDAP under CentOS7?

```
$ ldapsearch -b cn=config cn=config  olcTLSCipherSuite olcTLSProtocolMin
dn: cn=config
olcTLSCipherSuite: HIGH:!3DES:!aNull:!MD5:@STRENGTH
olcTLSProtocolMin: 3.1

$ nmap -Pn --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 636 ldap.example.com
Nmap scan report for ldap.example.com (198.51.100.1).
Host is up (0.00068s latency).
rDNS record for 198.51.100.1: ldap.example.com
PORT    STATE SERVICE
636/tcp open  ldapssl
| ssl-enum-ciphers: 
|   TLSv1.2: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: server
|_  least strength: A

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.73 seconds
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Red Hat this is a [known](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1474813) [bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1249093).

Comment: This bug has been subsequently fixed.